# Xilinx loop has iterated 64 times error

Tags: verilog, xilinx

I am writing code for a pipeline multiplication algorithm and while synthesizing using xilinx 10.1, I am getting the following error:

`"ERROR:Xst:1312 - Loop has iterated 64 times. Use "set -loop_iteration_limit XX" to iterate more"`.

How can I fix it or how can I find out what causes it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on information from Xilinx webpage:

> This error occurs if XST encounters a loop (typically a "while loop") that does not have a discrete termination. Rather than unrolling the loop forever, XST fails with this error during HDL analysis. A line number is not provided, but the error is reported within the context of the entity/module that is being analyzed.

You can solve that issue by adding e.g. `set -loop_iteration_limit 256` to `.xst` file in your project. Additional information you can find [here](http://china.xilinx.com/support/answers/18429.html).